# @font face is not working

Tags: css

I am trying to load a custom font from my server but it's not retrieving the font

I am using the following code, can some body tell me the one which i'm using is in correct format.

Code :

```
@font-face {  
      font-family: trcustomfont ;  
      src: url( http://content.sales-accredit.com/BTGOV/Fonts/Knowledge-Regular.otf ) format("opentype");  
}  

.customfont { 
      font-family: trcustomfont;  
}
```

Comment: Try using a relative link to the font file (relative to the CSS file) instead of the absolute link you have there.

Comment: Or use the best way for custom fonts like [Google fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts).

Comment: The link to your font file is a "403 - File not found", maybe that's why…

Comment: set this from your local storage

Comment: Are you loading your font from another domain?

Answer (score 0):

You should write like this :-

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
    src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    }
```

[**Or Read More About how to use custom fonts for our websites.....**](http://www.red-team-design.com/css3-font-face-or-how-to-use-a-custom-font-for-your-website)